# Error java.lang.String cannot be cast to metier.Motif

Tags: java, jcombobox

I work `JComboBox`es and `DefaultComboboxModel` that I fill with my database. Now I would like to save a `Enregistrement` in my database. But I get this error message

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to metier.Motif
```

This is my class Motif :

```
package metier;


public class Motif  { 

private Integer id;
private String libelle;
private Boolean recetteDepense;
Enregistrement enregistrements[];

public Motif() {
    this.id = null;
    this.libelle = "";
    this.recetteDepense = null;
}

public Motif(Integer id, String libelle, Boolean recetteDepense, Enregistrement[] enregistrements) {
    this.id = id;
    this.libelle = libelle;
    this.recetteDepense = recetteDepense;
    this.enregistrements = enregistrements;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLibelle() {
    return libelle;
}

public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
    this.libelle = libelle;
}

public Boolean getRecetteDepense() {
    return recetteDepense;
}

public void setRecetteDepense(Boolean recetteDepense) {
    this.recetteDepense = recetteDepense;
}

public Enregistrement[] getEnregistrement() {
    return enregistrements;
}

public void setEnregistrement(Enregistrement[] enregistrements) {
    this.enregistrements = enregistrements;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Motif{" + "id=" + id + ", libelle=" + libelle + ", recetteDepense=" + recetteDepense + ", enregistrements=" + enregistrements + '}';
}



}
```

And this is my function to save the `Enregistrement` :

```
public void enregistrerEnregistrement() throws DaoException {
    // Déclarations de variables locales
    dao = new DaoH2("gestComptes", "sa", "");
     try {
        dao.connecter();

        Motif motif = (Motif)(((VueAjouterEnregistrement)vue).getModeleJComboBoxMotif().getSelectedItem());            
        System.out.print(motif.getId());

        //dao.ajouterUnEnregistrement(id, idLibelle, idModeReglement, idCompte, idEtat, idMotif, PreLEnc, RecDep, DateEnr, montant, ancienSolde, nouveauSolde, dateFacture, numCHQ, anticipation);
    } catch (DaoException ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vue, "CtrlAjouterEnregistrement - instanciation - " + ex.getMessage(), "Enregistrement", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    }
```

My `Combobox`es work but I don't know how to recover the element with my getters and setters of my object `Motif`.

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to metier.Motif
at controleurs.CtrlAjouterEnregistrement.enregistrerEnregistrement(CtrlAjouterEnregistrement.java:235)
at vues.VueAjouterEnregistrement.jButtonValiderActionPerformed(VueAjouterEnregistrement.java:1288)
at vues.VueAjouterEnregistrement.access$000(VueAjouterEnregistrement.java:31)
at vues.VueAjouterEnregistrement$1.actionPerformed(VueAjouterEnregistrement.java:187)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: At which line, do you see the exception? Can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: Show please full stack trace of exception!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
Motif motif = (Motif)(((VueAjouterEnregistrement)vue)
                   .getModeleJComboBoxMotif().getSelectedItem());
```

you asume that `getSelectedItem()` returns a `Motif` where in fact it returns a `String`.

You shouldn't add strings to the combo box, but Motifs, and have Motif implement `toString` to be properly represented in the GUI. Then the `getSelectedItem` method will get you the selected Motif.

Comment: I've find thanx to you ! In fact, in my jcombobox I added the value and not the object. Thx and sorry for this stupid error !

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
Motif motif = (Motif)(((VueAjouterEnregistrement)vue).getModeleJComboBoxMotif().getSelectedItem());
```

you are trying to cast a String (returned by `(((VueAjouterEnregistrement)vue).getModeleJComboBoxMotif().getSelectedItem())`)

to a `Motif`.

That is not possible.

You can add a constructor to `Motif` that takes a `String` as a parameter, and then call that constructor.

**EDIT**

In your comment, you ask me how to call your constructor. IMHO, you should read a Java book or online tutorial, because calling a constructor is nothing magical. It's basic Java.

You could do:

```
String motifString = ((VueAjouterEnregistrement)vue).getModeleJComboBoxMotif().getSelectedItem(); 
Motif motif = new Motif(motifString);
```

Comment: I've created my constructor but how can i call it in my controller ?

Comment: Thx and I know how to call a constructor but this String is null. However I've data in my combobox.

Comment: If that's your problem, you should put that information into your question...